# Time complexity for Multiple for loops with same values

Tags: c#, algorithm, time, complexity-theory

Having 3 for loops which are the same, would this have a time complexity of O(n)?  OR  O(3n) ?

```
/* n > 0
 * n represents the problem size */

Foo(int n)
{
     sum = 0

     for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
          sum++
     }

     for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
          sum++
     }

     for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
          sum++
     }
     return sum
}
```

Comment: The complexity of n and 3n are relative and are the same.   You can say your for loop has three instructions so it is 3n.  Or you can say you for loop is going through the length of the array once an is n.  Usually if you are comparing one for loop algorithm against an algorithm that has 3 for loops you would say the one with 1 for loop is n and the one that has 3 for loops is 3n.  But when you have just one algorithm sometimes you say n and other times you say 3n.  Most people in this case will say 3n.

Comment: That's why I'm confused, as I have this question for an assignment and both options ( O(n) and O(3n)) ) are available :D I was thinking that you can drop the 3, but maybe there's a valid reason not to, since the same for loop is repeating for 3 times? boqq

Comment: As I said most people would say 3n since you have three for loops.  If you need to do both than O(n) is one for loop and O(3n) is three for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is O(n). If you have constant number of loops (three of them) it is just O(n). If number of loops is close to n, then it should be O(n^n). Everything in between it's up to you and depends on precision of your measurements for three loops it is O(3n), for 635 loops it is O(635n).